# Problema com aspas ao fazer INSERT SQL

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Estou fazendo um CRUD com PDO, mas a query do método prepare() só funciona com "aspas tortas"

Ex (assim funciona):

```
"INSERT INTO `_user` (`firstname`) VALUES ('blabla')"
```

Já assim não funciona:

```
"INSERT INTO '_user' ('firstname') VALUES ('blabla')"
```

Isso é problema com encoding ou algo assim?

Comment: Adicione o código e a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Não dá erro, a query só não funciona.

Comment: Você está usando MySQL?

Comment: Você deve usar backtick `\`` em nomes de campos ou tabelas, com prepared statements não é necessário usar aspas simples nos valores basta fazer o `bindValue()` ou passar todos os valores no `execute()`.

Comment: Sim, MySql com PDO

Comment: O Engraçado é que não tenho esse problema no select, isso é só no insert?

Comment: Não, a regra é a mesma em qualquer comando SQL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aspas simples só devem ser usadas em valores. Portanto estão ok em `VALUES ('blabla')`. Já em nomes de tabelas, colunas e *aliases*, ou você não usa nada, ou usa os *backticks* `` ` ``. Esses backticks só são obrigatórios se o nome da sua tabela, coluna ou alias corresponder a algum termo reservado do MySQL. Portanto, na sua segunda query, esta parte:

```
INSERT INTO '_user' ('firstname')
```

tem erros de sintaxe. A query correta mais simples ficaria assim (já numa string):

```
"INSERT INTO _user (firstname) VALUES ('blabla')"
```

Exemplo de uso que exige o backtick, se você tivesse uma coluna tipo INT chamada "order" (que é palavra reservada):

```
"INSERT INTO _user (firstname, `order`) VALUES ('blabla', 1)"
```

Não custa lembrar que **é sempre bom evitar utilizar palavras reservadas como nome de base de dados, tabela, coluna, alias, índice, função, procedure etc.**

Comment: Muito Obrigado, esclareceu legal!

Comment: Complementando, é posível usar palavras reservadas. Para isso, é necessário aplicar as aspas invertidas (backticks).

Answer (score 4):

os *backticks*, ou crase, ou "aspas tortas", fazem parte do padrão de identificadores do MySQL (não sei ao certo se da linguagem sql em si ou do SGDB).
Você pode ver mais sobre isso na [documentação do MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)